why flatpak can't search and how to fix it?
I use CentOS 7.9.2009. I've already installed Flatpak, and properly added flathub, using following:
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

But then when I search, I get:
[root@192 mozilla_qadjkl0]# flatpak search firefox
flatpak search: Failed to parse /var/lib/flatpak/appstream/flathub/x86_64/active/appstream.xml.gz file: Error on line 5556 char 29:
already set ' Organic Maps is a free Android & iOS offline maps app for travelers, tourists, hikers, drivers and cyclists. It uses crowd-sourced OpenStreetMap data and is developed with love by ' and tried to replace with ' (' No matches found

I asked chatgpt, it tells me use
sudo flatpak remote-delete flathub
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/flatpak/appstream/flathub/x86_64/active
sudo flatpak update --appstream

and after I do all this, the same problem still exists
[root@192 mozilla_qadjkl0]# flatpak search firefox
flatpak search: Failed to parse /var/lib/flatpak/appstream/flathub/x86_64/active/appstream.xml.gz file: Error on line 5556 char 29:
already set ' Organic Maps is a free Android & iOS offline maps app for travelers, tourists, hikers, drivers and cyclists. It uses crowd-sourced OpenStreetMap data and is developed with love by ' and tried to replace with ' (' No matches found

and when I use flatpak repair that also doesn't work.
I read other solutions, but not for CentOS; most are for Ubuntu, which I can't use.

welcome to U&L stack exchange. I've edited your question to try to clarify it, but I've had to make some guesses. Please feel free to edit your question if there's anything you'd like to clarify.
